# passing prop with navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am trying to send props with navigation. I am using stack-navigation package in react-native app.
I am using this example,
How can I send props inside this button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}>

I tried to do this one but didn't work.
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', name:items)}>

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title=Home
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ navigation,name }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details... again"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try to pass the same way,

```
 onPress={() => {
                      this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
                        title: item.title,
                      });
                    }}
```

while receiving can use the following way,

```
this.props.route.params.title
```

Comment: yes I am really sorry for asking this question. that was really easy and I found it :( Maybe it can be good example for other people.